# Defining connection string for mongoose in environments

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, railway.js

I've got a fairly "typical" setup (I'm using RailwayJS)

schema:

```
customSchema(function(){
    // Initialize Mongo DB
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb'); //todo: needs to come from connection or something?!

    var MyModel = new Schema({
        name : String,
        email : String,
        something : String
    });
});
```

My question is, how can I specify the connection string to use?

Should I move the mongoose.connect part out into my config section?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I like to use :

```
var mongourl = process.argv[2] || process.env.NODE_DB || 'mongodb://anywhere/db';
```

Remember to change `NODE_DB` to whatev er your env variable name is.

Note that I also allow to pass command line args (useful when using Cloud9 for running applications as this awesome service does not allow env variable). Index is 2 because the command is `node app.js mongodb://address`, remember to adjust if needed.

Comment: Here is the [Heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs#setting_node_env) on how to set up env variables (very easy). In your case just use `$ heroku config:add NODE_DB=mongodb://localhost/mydb`

Note : if you're using Heroku, take a look at [MongoHQ add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/mongohq) so you can try a free, easy to setup and to maintain mongodb service.